# Controlling the Author name field in the Bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I have been using Overleaf combined with a Mendeley web importer to create a `References.bib` file.  I didn't pay much attention because I thought it did what I wanted.  Now I need to make some corrections to my Bibliography.  I can sort out all the missing Journal names and such like but I decided that I'd like to change the lay out of the names.

I have a piece in my `Reference.bib` file which looks like this.

[image: Part of Reference.bib]

`\parencite(McDonald2015Mass-lossClusters)` generates

> (McDonald and Zijlstra, 2015)

in my text but my Bibliography output comes out like this:

[[image: Part of Bibliography output[2]]

I think that the main thing is that my Bibliography is consistent, but I see from other papers that the most common Bibliography author name convention would give

> McDonald I., Zijlstra A.A., 2015...

Up until now I just relied on the Mendeley wizard to sort my `Reference.bib` file out for me but I am thinking about downloading it and changing the `author` field to in notepad, and then re-uploading it, but I don't know what format the author field should like.

I want `\parencite()` to generate

> (surname and surname, year)

in the text and

> surname initial., surname initial. initial., year

in the bibliography.

Is it just a case of changing the layout of the `author` field, if so to what?

Thank you!

Edit:  If I amended the author field to this, would `\parencite{}` generate

> (McDonald and Zijlstra, year)

in the text and

> Mcdonald I., Zijlstra A.A., Year

in the bibliography?

> author = {McDonald, I and Zijlstra, A. A.},

Comment: You want `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use Biblatex bibliography styles

See link for details:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/biblatex_bibliography_styles